# map subscription values typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Hey does anyone know how this works. I have an angular project where i have a form in which a user can choose between two different answers. I now want to get the answers which he choose.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Test';
  
  answerNewCustomerControlChanges!: string;

  
  answers: any = [
    {value: '0', viewValue: 'Yes'},
    {value: '1', viewValue: 'No'}
  ];

  customerdataForm = new FormGroup({
    answerNewCustomerControl: new FormControl({value: "", disabled: false}, [Validators.required]),
    sapNumberControl: new FormControl({value: "", disabled: false}, [
      Validators.required
    ]),
    answerHaveSoftwareControl: new FormControl({value: "", disabled: false}, [
      Validators.required
    ])
  });

  onSelectionChanged(value: any) {
    var data = this.customerdataForm.get('sapNumberControl')?.getRawValue();
    console.log(data, "Da ist deine data");
    if (value.value.value === '0') {
      console.log("true");
      this.customerdataForm.get('sapNumberControl')?.disable();
      this.customerdataForm.get('answerHaveSoftwareControl')?.disable();
    } else {
      console.log("false");
      this.customerdataForm.get('sapNumberControl')?.enable();
      this.customerdataForm.get('answerHaveSoftwareControl')?.enable();
    }
  }


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.customerdataForm.get('answerNewCustomerControl')?.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
      console.log('firstname value changed')
      console.log(x.value);  
    })
  }
}
```

When i use the code in the ngAfterViewInit Function i get from the log
[image: Log]

This message. So i get the Object with the values in it.
I know i probably have to map this now on the value or viewValue but i dont know how that works.

Can anyone help or does anyone know a more elegant solution
thanks

EDIT:

When using the x.value command i get the Error

```
52       console.log(x.value);
                     ~


Error: src/app/app.component.ts:52:21 - error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.

52       console.log(x.value);
```

Comment: `x.value` will give you `"1"` and `x.viewValue` will give you `"No"`. What do you want to do with those values?

Comment: @ShamPooSham 

When i use x.value or x.view value i get the error
`Error: src/app/app.component.ts:52:19 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

52       console.log(x.value);
                     ~


Error: src/app/app.component.ts:52:21 - error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.

52       console.log(x.value);`

Comment: @ShamPooSham I want to write an api to get this values and display them in another component of my angular project. also want to use some other inputs to calculate with them

Comment: Where do you write `console.log(x.value)`? You can only access the content of x inside the subscribe function.

Comment: @ShamPooSham
`ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.customerdataForm.get('answerNewCustomerControl')?.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
      console.log('firstname value changed')
      console.log(x.value);  
    })
  }`

should be alright

Comment: I edited the question so there you can see where i use the x.value

Comment: Seems like x is sometimes an object and sometimes a string then. You should probably set the initial value of answerNewCustomerControl to be an object (`{value: '0'}`) instead of an empty string.

Comment: Since you default the control to an empty string, the string type is inferred to the value., whcih leads to the error. Please consider defaulting to undefined or an empy object.

Comment: @ShamPooSham that doesn work. I dont know why